# PHP upload files and give a custom name

Tags: php, upload

I am using this function to upload my files:

```
if ((($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["Artwork"]["size"] < 20000000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["Artwork"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["Artwork"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }else{
      $imageName = $_FILES['Artwork']['name'];
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Artwork"]["tmp_name"],
      $path_image . $imageName);
      }
    }else{
    //echo "invalid file";
    }
```

How do I change `$imageName = $_FILES['Artwork']['name'];` with a custom name, but mantaining the file extension in the name, so for example: `myCustomName.jpg`?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use the `['type']` field. That's user-provided data and is trivial to forge. use something server-side, such as [FileInfo](http://php.net/fileinfo), to get a mime-type. Still not 100%, but much better than the 0% reliability of the `['type']` field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only line you need modified in your code is:

```
$imageName = 'CustomName.' . pathinfo($_FILES['Artwork']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Where 'CustomName.' is the new name you want for the image.
[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) if the PHP function to handle the operations with paths and files names.

You whole code would be:

```
if ((($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["Artwork"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["Artwork"]["size"] < 20000000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["Artwork"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["Artwork"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }else{
      $imageName = 'CustomName.' . pathinfo($_FILES['Artwork']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Artwork"]["tmp_name"],
      $path_image . $imageName);
      }
    }else{
    //echo "invalid file";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ext = last(explode('.', $_FILES['Artwork']['name']));
$custom_name = 'something';
$imageName = $custom_name.'.'.$ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making it too complicated.  It's as simple as splitting the filename by the dot and using the last element:

```
$parts = explode('.', $_FILES['Artwork']['name']);
$newname = "myCustomName" . (size($parts) > 1 ? '.' . last($parts) : '')
```